# Help fix grub rescue

Tags: windows, ubuntu, grub, bootloader

I have windows 7 netbook. I repartitioned 100GB size and I installed Ubuntu 11.4 on it and boot master is GRUB.
Today, I accidentally chose Windows Recover Partition, it loaded up and I exited it right away. The computer restarted and Grub Rescue prompt came up.
error no such partition
grub rescue >

Can someone help me fix it? I have important data on both Ubuntu and Windows 7 that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is still there, don't reformat.

There are lots of things you can try to recover this situation.

### Backup | dd

First, use dd to copy your entire drive to another drive as backup, BEFORE doing anything else. This way you'll have something to revert to in case you take a wrong turn.

For [Example](http://www.linuxweblog.com/dd-image):

> dd if=/dev/hda conv=sync,noerror bs=64K | gzip -c  >
>   /mnt/sda1/hda.img.gz

### Partition Recovery | TestDisk

The Linux utility "[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)" has shown to be quite helpful to me for this kind of thing. Give that a try first.

### Booting | Super Grub Disk

You may find [Super Grub Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) profoundly helpful if you get your partitions in good shape, but just can't boot anymore.

### (edited) Booting | Windows Installation Disk

You can use the Windows Installer to "repair" your Windows installation so it boots again. Then you can fix grub any number of ways. A solution I actually prefer is to just use "[EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/EasyBCD+Documentation+Home)" to create an entry point to Grub using the Windows 7 boot manager (which is atypically excellent MS sw).

### Recovering if using GPT | gdisk

I've also found [gdisk](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+package/gdisk) to be outstanding, but if you're not using a gpt partition scheme, then that probably won't help you at all. Though, if you're running out of luck, give it a try, not sure if it'll work with MBR at all.

Comment: can I use Windows 7 DVD to fix the boot and get to Windows 7 first bootrec.exe  /fixmbr
bootrec.exe  /fixboot
bootrec.exe  /RebuildBcd
Then reinstall Grub using Ubuntu Live USB?

Comment: Yes, good call, that should be fine - though ONLY if your partition schema hasn't been messed up. And if you're really worried about your data, do that backup first. I've added your suggestion to my answer above.